# MongoDB $geoWithin Query Returning Incorrect Results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

Collection Schema:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59629006d5idf90ed8013932"),
"AssetNo" : "1",
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        -79.33801, 
        35.31775
    ]
}
```

Index on collection:

```
>db.temp.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "NearestNeighbor.temp"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "location" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "location_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "NearestNeighbor.temp",
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

Query:

```
db.temp.find({ "location" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" : [ [ -79.33519333 , 35.324] , 0.3 / 3963.2]}}})
```

This query returns zero documents. The distance between the two co-ordinate points is approximately 0.21 miles. (I wish to find points within a radius of 0.3 miles and the document above should ideally lie within the sphere/circle)

This is the query format I referred to:

```
db.<name>.find({
loc: { $geoWithin: 
 { 
    $centerSphere: [ [ long, lat ],
    radius in MILES/3963.2 ] } 
 }
})
```

On increasing the radius to 0.5 miles:

```
db.temp.find({ "location" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" : [ [ -79.33519333 , 35.324] , 0.5/3963.2]}}})
```

The document appears:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59629006d5idf90ed8013932"), "AssetNo" : "1", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -79.33801, 35.31775 ] } }
```

I tried debugging but couldn't find the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: GeoJSON Objects return their distances in "meters", so there are 1609.34 meters in a "mile".

Comment: I was miscalculating the distance between the two lat-long coordinates. It's actually 0.46 miles, the query was correct to not return any documents.

Comment: MongoDB Documentation here states that the centerSphere operator uses miles as an example (basically the earth's radius needs to be in the uni of preference for the radian conversion). 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/

Comment: That only applies to distances from "legacy coordinate pairs". It is also stated throughout the documentation that GeoJSOn objects return distances in meters.

Comment: @UmangDeora is this still an issue, or have you solved it?